# Append multiple childs C# XML

Tags: c#, excel, xml, append

I'm trying to generate an xml file with c# xml library
So this is one example of my expected XML output with the following c# code

```
<root>
    <PIDName PidName="$A011 - Current EQ Checksum">
        <MessageName MessageName="$22 - Read">
            <content>
                <ByteBit>0 [0]</ByteBit>
                <byteBitDescription>Read Data By Identifier Request</byteBitDescription>
                <QualifierID> </QualifierID>
            </content>
        </messageName>
    </PIDName>
</root>
```

This is my c# chuck of code, this loops through a excel file depending on the color of the cells, the basic logic is the important thing, because the code is more complex that this.

```
XmlElement pidname1= doc.CreateElement("PIDname");
XmlElement pidname2 = doc.CreateElement("MessageName");
XmlElement content = doc.CreateElement("Content");
while (row < MAX_ROW)
            {
                Range cell = worksheet.Cells[row++, col];

                //PID
                //This if say that if given cell color is blue enters to the conditional 
                if (cell.Interior.Color == colorPID)
                {
                    pidname1 = doc.CreateElement("PIDName");
                    pidname1.SetAttribute("PidName", cell.Value);
                    //rootnode.AppendChild(pidname1);
                    row++;
                }
                //Messages
                // if given cell color is gray enters to the conditional
                else if (cell.Interior.Color == colorMSG)
                {
                    Message message = new Message(cell.Value2);
                    pidname2.SetAttribute("MessageName", cell.Value);
                    pidname1.AppendChild(pidname2);



                    row++;
                    while (!IsRowEmpty(row))
                    {


                        ByteBit = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value);
                        ByteBitDescription = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value);
                        QualifierID = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value);

                        content = doc.CreateElement("Content");
                        XmlElement bB = doc.CreateElement("ByteBit");
                        XmlElement byteBitDescription = doc.CreateElement("byteBitDescription");
                        XmlElement qualifierID = doc.CreateElement("QualifierID");


                        bB.InnerText = ByteBit;
                        byteBitDescription.InnerText = ByteBitDescription;
                        qualifierID.InnerText = QualifierID;

                        content.AppendChild(bB);
                        content.AppendChild(byteBitDescription);
                        content.AppendChild(qualifierID);


                        pidname2.AppendChild(content);
                        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pidname2);
                        pidname1.AppendChild(content);

                        row++;
                    }

                    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pidname2);
                    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pidname1);


                }
```

For some reason im getting the following output, i dont understand why, i think its probably because im using multiple AppendChild one after the other.

```
<root>
    <MessageName MessageName="$22 - Read"> </messageName>
    <PIDName PidName="$A011 - Current EQ Checksum">
        <content>
            <ByteBit>0 [0]</ByteBit>
            <byteBitDescription>Read Data By Identifier Request</byteBitDescription>
            <QualifierID> </QualifierID>
        </content>
    </PIDName>
</root>
```

Comment: `doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pidname2);` seems weird. Why do you append it under document element if you want `MessageName` be the child of `PIDName` ?

Comment: Probably that's the thing that i'm not understanding...

Comment: How can i add a child of one element, For example MessageName being child of PIDname, like on Content being child of Pidname...

Comment: You've already done it by `pidname1.AppendChild(pidname2);`. Just remove `doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pidname2);`

Comment: Still the same lol

Comment: You should make a small test program to clarify it, not this production code. Since it's not a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no one can reproduce and help you. All we can do is telling you something is weird.

Comment: PIDName is a child of MessageName.  You are adding PIDName to root instead of to MessageName.